# Terraform HCL Loop over different providers to create different named aws_ssm_parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm, hcl

I need to generate dynamic aws_ssm_parameters per environment. Instead of hardcoding each of those data parameters. Is there a way to create data parameters with a for_each? I need to do something like this:

```
 envs = ["dev", "staging", "prod"]
 for_each envs

 data "aws_ssm_parameter" "example_endpoint_${env}" {
    provider    = "aws.${env}"
    name = "/example//GraphQLApi/GraphQLUrl"
  }
```

Then being able to access that variable based on environment. `data.aws_ssm_parameter.example_endpoint_${dev}`

Does anyone know a way to do something similar?

Comment: `provider` is not a valid option. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Marcin `provider` is a meta-argument available to all. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#selecting-alternate-provider-configurations

Comment: @jordanm AH yes, thanks. Got confused by its used.

Comment: @jordanm In this context it shoud not work. Provider can't be a variable.

Comment: Yeah, you're right